# Hide modules from current user in the navigation bar in Suitecrm

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am right now using LDAP authentication for adding user in Suitecrm. In normal course when the user is added to the system we can assign him roles during creation and also hide some modules which are enabled for him, in his portal .

With LDAP authentication I have been able to assign user to a role through code when he first logins but hiding modules for those users by code or otherwise has not been possible

Can anyone guide me as to how to hide modules from the current user which otherwise show in the navigation bar?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried disabling the module in the rolse access settings?

Comment: @mrbarletta yes I did but then the relate fields which are using it stop working.

Comment: I am not aware of any method to accomplish that in an upgrade safe fashion. - the last post here https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/26357  give you an idea of where to start looking

Answer (score 1):

There is upgrade safe manner to do it via smarty file.

1. Check your active theme and copy the file from `themes/<active_theme>/tpls/_headerModuleList.tpl` to `custom/themes/<active_theme>/tpls/_headerModuleList.tpl` (if custom directory doesn't exist then create it)
2. Search for  `groupTabs`, you will see `foreach loops` for processing it for different views. Hopefully, you can add your code there to do anything.